# Error while importing MongoClient from pymongo module

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pip, pymongo

I am trying to import MongoClient class from the pymongo module and getting the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pymongo.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pymongo
  File "C:\Users\Iqbal\Desktop\pymongo.py", line 5, in <module>
    client = pymongo.MongoClient()
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pymongo' has no attribute 'MongoClient' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I have installed latest version of pymongo, which is 3.10.1

```
import requests
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient()
```

Comment: What other messages are there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you named your file same as module name i.e, `pymongo.py`. Change it to something else and that should work for you.

Also delete the `pymongo.pyc` file if one was created next to it.

Comment: Yes, my file name was pymongo.py and I renamed it now. Thanks :-)

Comment: My project name was "pymongo"  i changed..and it worked

Comment: My file name was also 'pymongo' and it works as you guide. Thanks.